# How do I return all the values of only one of the table columns through a GET?

Tags: typescript, loopbackjs, loopback4

I have an API created with **Loopback4**, connected to a database and a table in mySQL.
Below is the structure of my table:

[image]

I want to write a function to create a **@GET** method to return all the **userID** (exclude the other fields).
Values returned are in JSON format, expected results are as below:

```
{
    "userID": 2192  
},
{
    "userID":1198
},
{
    "userID":5555
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `FilterBuilder` to include a particular attribute. Here is a related docs page: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Querying-data.html.

It will be something like below for the controller method:

```
let filterBuilder = new FilterBuilder(filter);
filterBuilder.fields('userID');
return this.testRepository.find(filterBuilder.filter);
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems like a simple solution, however as the userID column has duplicate userIDs, how can I have the response prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way to fetch the result of query in the form of array and then get column wise result on the basis of index.

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT u.id, u.userId, u.name, u.price FROM UserDetails u");
List<Object[]> rows = query.getResultList();
//This will give you the result of each column in array format
//userId will be at index 1
```